# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error in multiply 2 matrices

Tags: c#

When I run the script, I get the "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error at line `float[] i_f = b[itemid];`.

BTW, I changed

`for (int y = 0; y <= 114360000; y++)` to `for (int y = 0; y < 114360000; y++)` and also

`for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)` to `for (int x = 0; x < 8939500; x++)`

but it shows the same error again.

FYI: This code has two parts:

First part that get 100 values from 2 matrices and multiply them (matrix multiply) which works correctly.

Second part that repeats the first part for 1143600 times (The error happens when I run this part).

```
namespace function
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
        float userscore, itemscore,result;
        string lineitem, lineuser;
        //float[][] a = new float[89395][100];
        //float[][] b = new float[1143600][100];
        float[][] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 89395).Select(i => new float[100]).ToArray();
        float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray();
        //float[,] c = new float[89395, 100];
        StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\p.txt");
        StreamReader fileuser = new StreamReader("c:\\L.txt");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)
            {
                lineuser = fileuser.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineuser))
                {
                    string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');
                    int userid, factoriduser;
                    foreach (string value in values)
                    {
                        userid = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                        factoriduser = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                        userscore = Convert.ToSingle(values[2]);
                        a[userid][factoriduser] = userscore;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int y = 0; y <= 114360000; y++)
            {
                lineitem = fileitem.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lineitem))
                {
                    string[] valuesi = lineitem.Split(' ');
                    int itemid, factoriditem;
                    foreach (string value in valuesi)
                    {
                        itemid = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[0]);
                        factoriditem = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[1]);
                        itemscore = Convert.ToSingle(valuesi[2]);
                        b[itemid][factoriditem] = itemscore;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        public float dotproduct(int userid, int itemid)
        {

            //get the score of 100 from user and item to dotproduct
            //get userid and itemid element from array a and b
            float[] u_f = a[userid];
            float[] i_f = b[itemid];   //<-----error happens

            for (int i = 0; i < u_f.Length; i++)
            {
                //  result += u_f[userid] * i_f[itemid];
                result += u_f[i] * i_f[i];

            }
            return result;

        }

        private void btn_recomm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // if (txtbx_id.Text ==null)
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please insert user id");
            }
            //if (txtbx_id.Text != null && txtbx_itemid == null)
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_itemid.Text))
            {
                int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);


                if (sc >= 0 && sc <= 89395)
                {
                    //for (int z = 0; z <= 1143600; z++)
                    //{
                      //  dotproduct(sc, z);
                       // hashtable.Add(z, result);
                    //}
                    //SortedDictionary<int, float> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, float>(hashtable);
                    //foreach (int key in dict)
                    //{
                      //  System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", key, dict[key]));
                    //}
                    var results = new List<float>(1143600);
                    for (int z = 0; z <= 1143600; z++)
                    {
                        results.Add(dotproduct(sc, z));
                    }
                    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(10))
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", resultwithindex.Index, resultwithindex.result));
                    }
                    }



            }
            //if (txtbx_id!=null && txtbx_itemid!=null)
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_id.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_itemid.Text))
            {
                int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                // int uid;
                // if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbx_id.Text, out uid))
                // {
                // MessageBox.Show("Try again");
                // }

                int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text);
                // int iid;
                //if (!Int32.TryParse(txtbx_id.Text, out iid))
                //{
                //MessageBox.Show("Try again");
                //}
                //{
                if (uid >= 0 && uid <= 89395 && iid >= 0 && iid <= 1143600)
                {
                    dotproduct(uid, iid);
                    MessageBox.Show("The Score of item id " + iid + " is " + result);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: please simplify the code to a easy to follow example that demonstrates the issue, that is way too much code to follow thorough without a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You have declared arrays `a` with size `89395` and `b` with size `1143600` and trying to access the `89395`th element from array `a` and `1143600`th element from  array`b`.

**Solution :** you should always remember that array index always starts with `zero` and ends with `Length-1`.

So you can only access the elements from 0-89394 from array `a`  and
you can only access the elements from 0-1143599 from array `b`.

So you need to change your for-loop accordingly.

Replace This:

```
if (uid >= 0 && uid <= 89395 && iid >= 0 && iid <= 1143600)
{
  dotproduct(uid, iid);
  MessageBox.Show("The Score of item id " + iid + " is " + result);
}
```

With This:

```
if (uid >= 0 && uid < 89395 && iid >= 0 && iid < 1143600)
{
  dotproduct(uid, iid);
  MessageBox.Show("The Score of item id " + iid + " is " + result);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Replace this:

```
if (sc >= 0 && sc <= 89395)
```

With This:

```
if (sc >= 0 && sc < 89395)
```

Comment: Thank you @SudhakarTillapudi. Very useful info "array index always starts with zero and ends with Length-1". But unfortunately, it shows the same

Comment: @user3328039: check my edited answer with `solution 2`

Comment: I tried it @SudhakarTillapudi. . It must be correct because it doesn not show that error anymore. but the code shows nothing (error or output).